# Why im getting all the time InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know what does it mean but i don't understand why i'm getting it.
In my class constructor i did:

```
namespace HM
{
    class Core
    {
        public static Form1 form1;
        Process[] pname;
        private static List<float?> cpuSensorValues = new List<float?>();
        private static List<float?> gpuSensorValues = new List<float?>();
        Computer myComputer;
        Computer computer;

        public Core(Form1 f)
        {
            form1 = f;
            myComputer = new Computer();
            myComputer.CPUEnabled = true;
            myComputer.FanControllerEnabled = true;
            myComputer.MainboardEnabled = true;
            myComputer.Open();
            computer = new Computer();
            computer.Open();
            computer.GPUEnabled = true;
            OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.ISensor isss;
            Hardwares hwsd;
            OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.ISensor ist;
            pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("BFBC2Game");

        }
```

I added this:

```
pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("BFBC2Game");
```

And when the game is running i see using a breakpoint that pname wontain one index that is the game process. And im sure to run first the game then the program.

Then i have a method in the class i call it with a timer in Form1 that get write to a log file the temeperature of the GPU Video Card.
This part was working good untill i added this pname process.

```
if (gpuSensorValues.Count == 30 && sensor.Value >= (float)numericupdown)
                                        {
                                            float a = ComputeStats(gpuSensorValues).Item1;
                                            float b = ComputeStats(gpuSensorValues).Item2;
                                            float c = ComputeStats(gpuSensorValues).Item3;
                                            Logger.Write("********************************");
                                            Logger.Write("GPU Minimum Temperature Is ===> " + a);
                                            Logger.Write("GPU Maximum Temperature Is ===> " + b);
                                            Logger.Write("GPU Average Temperature Is ===> " + c);
                                            Logger.Write("********************************" + Environment.NewLine);
                                            gpuSensorValues = new List<float?>();
                                            pname.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Kill());

                                        }
```

I added this :

```
pname.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Kill());
```

I wanted that if the temperature for example was 123c then kill/close/shut down the game at once ! Instead it's not writing to the logger file the temperature anymore and it's never kill the process but writing to the log file the exception message:

```
3/5/2014--4:10 AM ==> There was an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()
   at HardwareMonitoring.Core.gpuView(Boolean pause, List`1 myData, Nullable`1 myGpuTemp, Button b1, Decimal numericupdown) in d:\C-Sharp\HardwareMonitoring\HardwareMonitoring\Hardwaremonitoring\Core.cs:line 172
```

This is the complete method code if needed:

```
public float? gpuView(bool pause, List<string> myData, float? myGpuTemp, Button b1, decimal numericupdown)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pause == true)
                {
                }
                else
                {


                    foreach (var hardwareItem in computer.Hardware)
                    {
                        if (form1.videoCardType("ati", "nvidia") == true)
                        {
                            HardwareType htype = HardwareType.GpuNvidia;

                            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == htype)
                            {

                                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                                {

                                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                                    {

                                        sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                        if (sensor.Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                                        {

                                            /* else if (UpdatingLabel(sensor.Value.ToString(), label16.Text.Substring(0, label16.Text.Length - 1)))
                                             {
                                                 //  Label8 = GpuText;
                                             }*/
                                            //myData = new List<string>();
                                            //this.Invoke(new Action(() => data = new List<string>()));
                                            if (!form1.IsDisposed)
                                            {
                                                form1.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Gpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
                                            }
                                            //this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = null));
                                            //this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = data));



                                            //form1.Invoke(new Action(() =>  lb1.DataSource = myData));
                                            //sensor.Value.ToString() + "c";
                                            myGpuTemp = sensor.Value;
                                            //label8.Visible = true;
                                        }
                                        //if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                        //{
                                        gpuSensorValues.Add(sensor.Value);
                                        if (gpuSensorValues.Count == 30 && sensor.Value >= (float)numericupdown)
                                        {
                                            float a = ComputeStats(gpuSensorValues).Item1;
                                            float b = ComputeStats(gpuSensorValues).Item2;
                                            float c = ComputeStats(gpuSensorValues).Item3;
                                            Logger.Write("********************************");
                                            Logger.Write("GPU Minimum Temperature Is ===> " + a);
                                            Logger.Write("GPU Maximum Temperature Is ===> " + b);
                                            Logger.Write("GPU Average Temperature Is ===> " + c);
                                            Logger.Write("********************************" + Environment.NewLine);
                                            gpuSensorValues = new List<float?>();
                                            pname.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Kill());

                                        }
                                            b1.Enabled = true;
                                        //}
                                        //form1.Select();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            HardwareType htype = HardwareType.GpuAti;

                            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == htype)
                            {

                                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                                {

                                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                                    {

                                        sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                        if (sensor.Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                                        {

                                            myGpuTemp = sensor.Value;
                                            //label8.Visible = true;
                                        }
                                        if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                        {
                                            Logger.Write("The Current Ati GPU Temperature Is ===> " + sensor.Value); 
                                            b1.Enabled = true;
                                        }
                                        form1.Select();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("There was an exception: " + err.ToString());
            }
            return myGpuTemp;
        }
```

Line 172 is:

```
//form1.Select();
```

Just empty line nothing to do there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for Process.Kill() show that it can raise an InvalidOperationException if the process is not running.

Maybe try: `pname.Where(p => !p.HasExited).ToList().ForEach(p => p.Kill());`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one or more of the instances in your `pname` list aren't in the state you expect. As pointed out in another answer this could be because the process isn't running. Also, one of the references could be `null`. To prevent the exception try adding a where clause like the following;

```
 pname.ToList().Where(p != null && !p.HasExited).ForEach(p => p.Kill());
```

I'm not familiar with the `Process` class so I'm not entirely sure what you'll want to use for that second condition in the `Where` but that should give you the idea. This will just filter out instances in the list that would cause the error before calling `Kill()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i can see in your code is you are not clearing the pname object. If the pname has reference to a process that is no longer running, you will get this exception. I recommend to get fresh list of process when you want to stop it. Replace the following line

```
pname.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Kill());
```

with

```
pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("BFBC2Game");
pname.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Kill());
```